# How to call RequireJS functions in other files? How to separate RequireJS files?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Instead of having one giant js file that has a whole bunch of  "defines", how do I call my various "define" functions from other files?

I've been copying these examples, but still cannot get it to work:

- [example-multipage](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)
- [example-multipage-shim](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim)
- [example-jquery-shim](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim)

Here is what I have so far:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
       jquery: '../libraries/jquery-1.10.2.min',
       simControlView: '../javascripts/simControlView'
    }
});

require(['jquery','loadPage'], function( $,loadPage) 
{ 
        loadPage();
});

define('loadPage', ['jquery'], function($)
{
    var simControlView = require(['./simControlView']);
    return function()
    {
         simControlView.showSimControlView(); //having problem here

    };
});
```

**simControlView.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return {
        showSimControlView: function () {
            console.log("Hi!!");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> **Uncaught TypeError**: Object function d(e,c,h){var
>   g,k;f.enableBuildCallback&&(c&&H(c))&&(c.__requireJsBuild=!0);if("string"===typeof
>   e){if(H(c))return v(A("requireargs", "**Invalid require
>   call**"),h);if(a&&s(N,e))return Ne;if(j.get)return
>   j.get(i,e,a,d);g=n(e,a,!1,!0);g=g.id;return!s(r,g)?v(A("notloaded",'**Module**
>   name "'+g+'" **has not been loaded yet for context**: '+b+(a?"":". **Use
>   require([])**"))):r[g]}K();i.nextTick(function(){K();k=q(n(null,a));k.skipMap=f.skipMap;k.init(e,c,h,{enabled:!0});C()});return
>   d} **has no method 'showSimControlView'**

See anything I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving all the dependencies to the dependency list you pass to `define()`.

Also, the ordering may be important. I.e. the `define()` of a module may need to come before the `require()` that requires it (talking about the `'loadPage'` module).

Also, if your `paths` config calls a module `'simControlView'`, then it needs to be referred to as `'simControlView'`, and not as `'./simControlView'`.

E.g.:

```
define('loadPage', ['jquery', 'simControlView'], function($, simControlView) {
    return function() {
         simControlView.showSimControlView();
    };
});

require(['jquery', 'loadPage'], function($, loadPage) {
    loadPage();
});
```

Comment: Worked! Wow all this time I was messing around with it and this was all it took. Thank you!!